# C++ Template Classes, Inheritance and Writing Generic Code for Graph Drawing

Tags: c++, inheritance

## Background Info

I am writing a graph-drawing program. I have encountered a problem with templates and inheritance, and I do not know how to proceed. I do not know how I should design my code to enable me to do what I am trying to do. (Explanation below.)

## Target

I have a template class, which represents "data". It looks something like the following:

```
template<typename T>
class GraphData
{
    std::vector<T> data_x;
    std::vector<T> data_y; // x and y should be held in separate vectors
}
```

This class is part of an inheritance hierarchy involving several classes.

The hierarchy looks something like this... (Sorry this is from my notes, awful diagram.)[image: Inheritance Diagram]

*Explanation*

- There is a base class. No real reason to have it right now, but I anticipate using it later.
- Base_Legend adds functionality for legend drawing. New members added include a `std::string`, and Get/Set functions.
- Base_Drawable adds a pure abstract `= 0` member. `void Draw(...)`. This is to force overloading in all inherited objects which are drawable.
- GraphData_Generic adds functionality for adding/removing data points to a set of vectors. These are pure abstract methods, and must be overridden by any data classes which inherit.
- GraphData and HistogramData are 2 data types which have implementations of the functions from GraphData_Generic. (No implementation of `Draw()`.)
- GraphData_GenericDrawable doesn't do anything. It is to be used as a base class pointer, so that a vector of these objects can be used as data (add/remove data points) and can be draw (using `void Draw()`). This class also can be used to call the `Get()`/`Set()` methods for the `std::string` to be used in the legend.
- Finally, at the bottom are GraphData_Drawable and HistogramData_Drawable which overload the `void Draw()` function. This code specifies exactly how the data should be drawn, depending on whether we have a Histogram or general set of data points.

## Problem

Currently, I am using template types. The type of data for the datapoints / histogram bin values is specified by using a template.

For example, one can have a `HistogramData<double`, `HistogramData_Drawable<double>`, `HistogramData_Drawable<int>`, etc... Similarly, one can have `GraphData<double>`, `GraphData<float>,` GraphData_Drawable`, etc...

So hopefully it should be fairly obvious what's going on here without me uploading my ~ 10000 lines of code...

Right, so, in addition I have some `class Graph`, which contains a `std::vector<GraphData_Generic_Drawable*>`, hence the use of the base class pointer, as suggested above.

BUT! One has to decide what type of data should be used as the underlying type. I MUST choose either `std::vector<GraphData_Generic_Drawable<double>*>` or `std::vector<GraphData_Generic_Drawable<float>*>`.

This isn't useful, for obvious reasons! (I could choose `double` and force the user to convert all values manually, but that's just an easy way out which creates more work later on.)

A (very) ugly solution would be to have a `std::vector<>` for each possible type... `int` `long` `unsigned long long` `double` `float` `unsigned char`... etc...

Obviously this is going to be hideous and essentially repeat loads of code..

So, I intend to implement an `AddData` method which adds data to that vector, and I also currently have the following method:

```
// In class Graph

void DrawAll()
{
    for(std::vector<GraphData_Drawable*>::iterator it = m_data.begin(); it != m_data.end(); ++ it)
         (*iterator)->Draw(arguments);
} // Draw function takes arguments including a canvas to draw to, but this isn't directly relevant to the question
```

Which iterates over the vector and calls `Draw` for each set of data in there.

## How to fix it?

My current thoughts are something along the lines of; I need to implement some sort of interface for an underlying data class, which retrieves values independent of the underlying type. But this is only a very vague initial idea and I'm not really sure how I would go about implementing this, hence the question... I'm not sure this is even what I should be doing...

If this isn't clear ask me a question and I'll update this with more details.

Comment: Couldn't understand what is going on... If you want to parameterize type T of `std::vector<GraphData_Generic_Drawable<T>*>` parameter, you have to make template from class `Graph`. Or there are some problems with that? What do arrows represent on your diagram? Sometimes they represent has-a relationship but not always I guess.

Comment: @George The arrows are "this class is inherited from that class", eg; `GraphData_Base_Legend` inherits from `GraphData_Base`

Comment: It's a bit off topic but, if all arrows are inheritance, you should review your design according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle. It's very likely that less coupled design will help to solve your problem.

Comment: In your case, the only way to adjust types of parent objects is to parameterize child object.